# Selenium webdriver ruby: Unable to read text value some times

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

Scenario:

1. There is a text in my webpage
2. I am using **xpath** to locate it

   ```
   myxpath=//table[@id='table44']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/span[2]
   ```
3. I am trying to get it value using

   ```
   value=driver.find_element(:xpath, myxpath).text
   ```

But problem is :sometimes it gets value & sometime it doesn't
& i am not able to understand the cause of this problem

Any alternative that i can try ?

Comment: Your 2 lines *I am getting it value using* and *But its not able to get value* are contradicting each other..

Comment: @arup 1. sometimes it gets value & sometime it doesn't
2. I have made necessary changes in my post/question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write using [`explicit wait`](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits).

```
my_xpath = "//table[@id='table44']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/span[2]"
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
element = wait.until { driver.find_element(:xpath, my_xpath) }
puts element.text
```